# Blazor 8 wwwroot index.html

Tags: blazor, azure-static-web-app, .net-8.0

I'm playing with Blazor 8.
When I publish the project, there is no index.html in the output:

[image]

It causes trouble when deploying on static web app, because it is expecting this file.

Thanks for the help!

I tried to add the index.html in the app, but it is not linked to the blazor app

Comment: Index.html is available only for WebAssembly applications, make sure you are not using Blazor server.

Comment: @JTO Hope this reference [helps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor.md)

Comment: I tried to do the @Sampath reference, and I get the same error:
```Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (wwwroot). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html```
when deploying

Comment: @DA I am using the WebAssembly application

Comment: @Sampath I just used the initial template with the counter: File new blazor web app

Comment: @JTO please try this git [reference](https://github.com/new?template_name=blazor-starter&template_owner=staticwebdev)

Comment: @Sampath yes, I saw this one, but it is using .net 7. I am using .net 8. I think it is a change since .Net 8, but I can't find anything on the missing index.html...

Comment: @JTO What is the Visual Studio Version you are using ?

Comment: @Harshitha I am using VS 17.8.0

Comment: Yes.. I have done repro with VS 17.8.0 .. Please check the below solution and let me know

Answer (score 0):

> because it is expecting this file.

Yes, to run the Blazor Web Assembly App we need an `index.html` file which is in the `wwwroot` directory of the Application.

- Razor pages will be loaded on top of the index.html file.

***Check the below Workaround to deploy Blazor Web Assembly App to Azure Static Web Apps.***

- Created a Blazor Web Assembly App with .NET 8.0 Version.
- Create a new Repository in GitHub.
- The commands to push the code from Visual Studio to GitHub repro will be available when you create a new repo.

```cs
  git init
  git add README.md
  git commit -m "first commit"
  git branch -M main
  git remote add origin https://github.com/YourOrgName/RepoName.git
  git push -u origin main
```

- In local, you can see `.git` folder with `index.html` page in it.

[image]

- Cross the repo once after pushing the code. Make sure all the files and folders exists.

***My `GitHub` Folder:***

[image]

- Create a new Static WebApp in Azure Portal.

***Build Details:***

```cs
Build Presets - Blazor
App Location - / 
Output Location - wwwroot
```

- As my code files are in the root directory of GitHub,I have mentioned as `/`.
- If you have code in any other folder you need to mention the folder name.

***Deployment:***

[image]

To confirm that my `index.html` is loading, I have added a bit of line as below in `index.html` file.

```cs
<P>Hello this is Index.html file</P>
```

- Whenever I tried to run the app, I can see the `Hello this is Index.html file` line in all the navigations.

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Deploying  an index.html file makes the app delivering works, but the real blazor app is not delivered. In my app, I added a blank index.html in wwwroot, then I deployed, and a blank page appears on the azure static website.

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure.If possible please share the code repo

Comment: @JTO - Dont you have `index.html` file by default in your `wwwroot` local folder ?

Comment: @spt Unfortunately, it did not solved my issue.

Here is my repo:

https://github.com/jtourvieille/ResourceCalendar/tree/main/ResCalApp

Comment: Will try to check with your repo

Comment: Are you working with client app?

Comment: Which [template](https://i.imgur.com/APpmYoV.png) you have selected.I have selected Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App.

Comment: I selected theses options:

Blazor web app

Framework: 8.0
Auth: None
Https: yes
Interactive render mode: WebAssembly
Interactivitylocation: Per page/component
Include sample pages: yes
Do not use top level statements: no

Comment: Trying to deploy the app with the above configurations.Will let you know once done.

Comment: Yes,even for me it is displaying only the same , a blank page without Blazor app.Instead of Blazor Web(WebAssembly), why can't you go with direct Blazor WebAssembly which is much easier.

Comment: You can even check MSDoc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/gitlab?tabs=blazor)